# Accessing URL parameters - PHP & Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

So my website is PHP for the backend and AngularJS for the frontend. Weird that I'm finding that I have to use PHP on the frontend to achieve some things like getting URL paramters. Explanation below;

Given the following URLs for example

```
http://www.test.co.uk/search-menu/1/cinamon-soho
http://www.test.co.uk/search-restaurant?location=asokoro&day=today&time=1100
```

My Angular code in the same page requires the parameters location, day etc.
Right now I'm having to use the line below to pass them to angular

```
$scope.l = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['location']); ?>;
```

My questions are;

1. Is there a way to access these variables using just Angular so I can take PHP out of the equation?
2. If question 1 is possible, how can I do the same if I then decide to move my Angular code away from that page to a dedicated `.js` page that I reference using

`<script src="http://www.test.co.uk/js/main.js"></script>`

**FYI**

The website was not built from the ground up using AngularJS. Angular was later introduced to the frontend heavy lifting PHP was doing so the website is not a **SPA**. There's no angular routing in place.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use `window.location`?

Comment: If it will work why not... How do I use it?

Comment: Use the `$location.search` method. See [AngularJS $location API Reference -- search](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search). <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a function like below

```
function fetchGetVariables() {
  var loc = "http://www.test.co.uk/search-restaurant?location=asokoro&day=today&time=1100";
  // var loc = window.location.href; // Use this in actual use
  var result = {};

  var parts = loc.split("?");

  if (parts.length > 0) {
    var params = parts[1].split("&");

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
      var keyValuePair = params[i].split("=");

      var key = keyValuePair[0];
      var value = "";
      if (keyValuePair.length > 0) {
        value = keyValuePair[1];
      } 

      result[key] = value;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(fetchGetVariables());
```

This gives the output:

```
Object {location: "asokoro", day: "today", time: "1100"}
```

See it at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/fz4oa4eu/2/) fiddle.

Comment: How about for a URL like this that has been made pretty `http://www.test.co.uk/search-menu/1/cinamon-soho`... I need to extract either `1` or `cinamon-soho`

Answer (score 2):

I got this code that works fine :

```
function $_GET(param) {
    var vars = {};
    window.location.href.replace( 
        /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
        function( m, key, value ) { // callback
            vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
        }
    );

    if ( param ) {
        return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
    }
    return vars;
}
```

(source : http://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/javascript/recuperer-parametres-get-url-javascript)

You can then use it like the PHP `$_GET`, but with parentheses instead of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular you can pull the values from the URL with the $routeParams.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams#!